# Debian - add disk and resize main partition

Tags: linux, debian, disk, ssd, resize2fs

I've added new disk to server and now I need to resize main `/` partition with this space.
I remember few years ago that I have done something like this but every tutorial on the net is about adding this space to new location in example: `/mnt/newspace` but thats not the goal.
I need to use only fdisk + resize2fs if this is possible, but there is no lvm and no network connection. Can someone help me to resize only this `/` with this tools ?
I was trying whole day on VMs but with no result and I can't damage rest of data.

I can see this new disk under `lsblk` as `/dev/sdb`, existing disk is `/dev/sda` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions cannot span multiple disks so if you are really using plain partitions without LVM or software RAID you can't resize your root partition.

If you don't want to use the new disk for a separate mount point (like placing your `/home` on it), you can create an MD RAID array from the two disks, it is possible to do that without reinstalling your system, you can follow [this how to from Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Convert_a_single_drive_system_to_RAID) (you'll need to create a degraded array on the new disk, copy the data on it and the add the first disk to the array).

Similarly you could also create LVM volume group on the new disk, copy your `/` to a new logical volume and after that add the first disk to the VG and resize the logical volume.

You can also try [converting your ext filesystem to btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3) and then [add the second disk](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Adding_new_devices) to your btrfs volume.

Note that with all of the above you'll also need update your `/etc/fstab`, rebuild initramfs and adjust GRUB configuration to make it work.

Also make sure to make a backup first. Lot of things can co wrong when working with storage.

Comment: There’s another possibility: device-mapper can be used without LVM to build a block device spanning two or more other devices.

Comment: (The difficulty then is how to ensure the device is correctly setup during boot...)

Comment: DM would be a nice solution, especially because you could create a dm-linear device over the two disks and just resize the filesystem. But without grub and init support for something like that it would be really hard to make this work especially for `/`. That's why we have LVM :-)